# .htaccess for unknowns

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

Alright, so here is what I'm hoping for...

Any request to this

http://www.fileorchard.com/3451928347592

will rewrite to http://www.website.com/joke.php?j=3451928347592

but also, I would like this to be possible as well

http://www.website.com/3451928347592-dswkfjawe/asdoiw-aweofiwe

Essentially, I would like to grab the numbers, and ignore anything after them.

This is what I have so far

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/?$ joke.php?j=$1  [NC]
```

This works for just the simple http://www.website.com/3451928347592
but the rest don't work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe `RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)(.*)/?$ joke.php?j=$1  [NC]` ?

Comment: Works great until I add a / anywhere after the number, then it redirects to the correct page, but all of the images and everything is lost. Essentially anything that doesn't have a the full url (<img src"http://www.w.com/img.png"> works but <img src="/img.png"/> fails) fails

Comment: Yes because the browser "thinks" you would be in a different directory so it tries to load the image from there. You have to use absolute links there...

Comment: Yeah I understand that, I just thought there was a way around that.'

Comment: I'll leave this open a bit longer in case anyone has a way around that.

Comment: the only way around that is redirecting with PHP. In the target PHP-file you could check whether there is a "/" after the numbers, if yes you could change URL that there isn't that / anymore. But is that so important? Where is the problem with just using absolute paths? Anyway, another way around that doesn't exist. This is a browser problem...